# Getting TableViewCell Index is nil on dropdown item selection

Tags: ios, swift, indexing, tableview, dropdown

I want tableviewcell index on dropdown item selection. But the index is nil when I am clicking on dropdown item. Is there any way to  get index on dropdown item selection? If anyone have any better solution give me some idea.

```
let EditDropDown = DropDown()
lazy var dropDowns: [DropDown] = {
    return [
        self.EditDropDown
    ]
}()
```

This is my function which I am using for DropDown List.

```
func setupGenderDropDown() {

        let cellHeader = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellRIDHeader") as! SPOccupationCell

        EditDropDown.anchorView = cellHeader.btnDots
        EditDropDown.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 40)

        // You can also use localizationKeysDataSource instead. Check the docs.
        EditDropDown.dataSource = [
            "Edit",
            "Make Default",
            "Delete"
        ]

        // Action triggered on selection
        EditDropDown.selectionAction = { [weak self] (index, item) in
            cellHeader.btnDots.setTitle(item, for: .normal)

            if item == "Edit"
            {
                // I am Getting Cell Index but index is nil
                let cell = self!.tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellRIDHeader") as! SPOccupationCell

                let indexPath = self!.tableview.indexPath(for: cell)
                    print(indexPath as Any)

                let occupation_id = self!.arrayOccupation[(indexPath?.row)!].occupation_Main_id
                    print(occupation_id)

                    let next = self!.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditOccupationVCSID") as! EditOccupationVC
                self!.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated: false)
                    next.occupationId = occupation_id



            }
            else if item == "Make Default"
            {
                print("B")
            }
            else if item == "Delete"
            {
                print("c")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi.  I presume that `EditDropDown` is an open source component or similar.  Can you provide details of that?  You should never call `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRow(at:)`.  You will get `nil` from `indexPath(for: cell)` because the cell you have has just been returned; it isn't associated with any row in the table.  Don't you want to do something with the `index` that was passed to your closure? Or do you have the drop down in a cell and that is the index you are trying to find?

Comment: @Paulw11 I updated the code.

Comment: Ok.  That shows how you declare `EditDropDown` (which I assumed was a class because it starts with a capital; you should call it `editDropDown` by convention), but I was referring to a link to the web page that describes the `DropDown` class. When you are using something that isn't part of `UIKit` it is helpful if you provide details on it.

Comment: Also, it still isn't clear what "index" you are after.

Comment: @Paulw11 But what will the effect of this. But I have been changed. Now I just want to know how can I get index. Can you give some example or any idea.

Comment: @Paulw11 I just want Tableviewcell index on click of Dropdown item's click.

Comment: Which table view cell?  You haven't shown any details of any table view or cell.  Is this code contained in your table view cell subclass?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using [DropDown](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown) library to show dropdown. There is a problem where you are getting cell when it is tapped so I have created a demo project (simple tableView and not with custom `UITableViewCell`) for you and I have added comment to explain the changes. Consider below code:

```
import UIKit
import DropDown

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var items: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift"]

    let editDropDown = DropDown() //Object name should start with small letter

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func setupGenderDropDown(cell: UITableViewCell) { //Pass your cell with argument and change type to your custom cell

        //By changing cell argument with your custom cell you will get your button for anchor
        editDropDown.anchorView = cell.textLabel
        editDropDown.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 40)

        editDropDown.dataSource = [
            "Edit",
            "Make Default",
            "Delete"
        ]

        //Here you need to update selectionAction from their library page
        editDropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in

            //Here you will get selected item and index
            print("Selected item: \(item) at index: \(index)")
            if item == "Edit"
            {
                print(item)
                print(index)
            }
            else if item == "Make Default"
            {
                print("B")
            }
            else if item == "Delete"
            {
                print("c")
            }
        }

        //This was missing in your code
        editDropDown.show()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        //Get the selected cell this way
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }
        guard let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { return }

        //Pass your selected cell to setupGenderDropDown method
        setupGenderDropDown(cell: currentCell)
    }
}
```

[HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=44491198948480530843) you can check demo project. And it's created into Xcode 10.1